# Nginx + Wysiwyg + CKeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I've got several sites up and running on Nginx, but no editor loads.  Wysiwyg is configured properly with CKeditor downloaded and in the libraries directory.

At this point I'm unsure if its something I'm missing, or something in my config that is blocking it.

The current configuration is the following.

```
#######################################################
### nginx.conf catch-all
#######################################################

client_max_body_size 75M;

gzip_static on;
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# This is mostly based on Drupal's stock .htaccess
location ~* ^.+(\.(txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
    return 404;
}

# serve static files directly
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|swf|flv)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}

## Deny some crawlers
if ($http_user_agent ~* (HTTrack|HTMLParser|libwww) ) {
    return 444;
}

## Deny certain Referers (case insensitive)
if ($http_referer ~* (poker|sex|girl) ) {
    return 444;
}

## 6.x starts
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; # remove trailing slashes - disabled
    try_files $uri @cache;
}

location @cache {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
        return 405;
    }

    error_page 405 = @drupal;
    add_header Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT"; 
    add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 1.9"; 
    charset utf-8;
    try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_$args.html /cache/$host${uri}_$args.html @drupal;
}

location @drupal {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~* (/\..*|settings\.php$|\.(htaccess|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|pl|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template))$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~* /files/.*\.php$ {
    return 444;
}

location ~* /themes/.*\.php$ {
    return 444;
}

location ~ \.css$ {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
        return 405;
    }

    error_page 405 = @uncached;
    access_log off;
    expires max; #if using aggregator
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.1";
    try_files /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.css /cache/$host${uri}_.css $uri =404;
}

location ~ \.js$ {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
        return 405;
    }

    error_page 405 = @uncached;
    access_log off;
    expires max; # if using aggregator
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.2"; 
    try_files /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.js /cache/$host${uri}_.js $uri =404;
}

location ~ \.json$ {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
    return 405;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
    return 405;
    }

    error_page 405 = @uncached;
    access_log off;
    expires max; # if using aggregator
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.3"; 
    try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.json /cache/$host${uri}_.json $uri =404;
}

location @uncached {
    access_log off;
    expires max; # max if using aggregator, otherwise sane expire time
}

location ^~ /sites/default/files/imagecache/ {
    index index.php index.html;

    # assume a clean URL is requested, and rewrite to index.php
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        break;
    }
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~* \.xml$ {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
        return 405;
    }
    error_page 405 = @drupal;
    add_header Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT";
    add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.4"; 
    charset utf-8;
    types { }
    default_type application/rss+xml;
    try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.xml /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.html /cache/$host${uri}_.xml $uri @drupal;
}

location ~* /feed$ {
    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
        return 405;
    }
    error_page 405 = @drupal;
    add_header Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT";
    add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.5"; 
    charset utf-8;
    types { }
    default_type application/rss+xml;
    try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.xml /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.html /cache/$host${uri}_.xml $uri @drupal;
}

#######################################################
### nginx.conf catch-all
#######################################################
```

I've uninstalled the WYSIWYG module, reinstalled it, and it cannot see CKeditor. If I paste the URL into the address bar, I can access the CKeditor.js file directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you do not have CKeditor installed twice. Its easy to do this with the CKeditor module (which I used on older sites) and the WYSIWYG module which requires CKeditor in a different directory.
WYSIWYG has issues detecting newer versions of CKeditor. The issue queue has several related issues. Downgrading was the simplest way to resolve it.
Cutting edge features on a CDN can behave poorly or interact in unexpected ways.